# how to make video fit the full width the page but height only 20% or less

Tags: html, css, html5-video

```css
video {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://www.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/videos/16719199/preview/stock-footage-old-retro-video-game-arcade-clouds-moving-on-a-blue-sky-and-grass.webm" autoplay loop />
</video>
```

I want to add a banner sort of thing on the webpage. I'm using this code. the width fits automatically to fit the width of the page but I am unable to adjust the height. I want to be able to add navigation under the video. but this video is taking up the whole page. please someone help adjust the height of the video so that it appears on a quarter of the page

Comment: What part of the video do you want it to show given the mismatches between video aspect ratio and viewports aspect ratios?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the styles below. The downside is that a `video` does not scale like an `img` does in the browser. This means unless your video is wide and short (i.e., 2500px x 250px) then it won't be able to scale with the parent being `height: 20%;`.

However, you can reposition the video within the parent container by adjusting the `top` value on `.video-container video`.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 20%;
}

.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay loop> 
    <source src="https://www.shutterstock.com/shutterstock/videos/16719199/preview/stock-footage-old-retro-video-game-arcade-clouds-moving-on-a-blue-sky-and-grass.webm"> 
  </video>
</div>
```